# How to split a string with multiple special characters or delimiters into separate fragments using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that has a string column as shown below:

| StringCol |
| --- |
| abcd_45dl/beta3,test |
| a56d/beta_46ab |

I would like to split each fragment at every special character such as (/,-_^. etc).
Currently I am using the following line but this only gives me the first fragment.

```
 SUBSTRING(terms, 0, PATINDEX('%[-!?@#$%^&*()_+=<>.:;/|\]%', terms))
```

The desired output would like like this:

| StringCol | StringPc |
| --- | --- |
| abcd_45dl/beta3,test | abcd |
| abcd_45dl/beta3,test | 45dl |
| abcd_45dl/beta3,test | beta3 |
| abcd_45dl/beta3,test | test |
| a56d/beta_46ab | a56d |
| a56d/beta_46ab | beta |
| a56d/beta_46ab | 46ab |

Comment: Please always specify the version of SQL Server you're using. https://sqlblog.org/ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2017+ it provides *translate* that can help here combined with *string_split*:

```
with sample as (
 select 'abcd_45dl/beta3,test' StringCol union all
 select 'a56d/beta_46ab'
)
select *
from sample
cross apply String_Split(Translate(StringCol,'_/',',,'),',')
```